# Why work done is zero on bringing a charge from infinity to a point where there is no electric field?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electrostatics, work

According to me we will apply a force on the charge and it will do a certain displacement to reach that point from infinity where we wanted to bring it and at that point there is no electric field. But still we applied force and displacement also occurred therefore work done should not be zero. Please explain me the concept and please tell me where am i going wrong?

Comment: Why do you think you are wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although there is no work due to the electric field, work associated with the force and displacement has been done. In classical mechanics, a force is said to do work when there is a displacement of the centre of mass of the body on which the force is applied.

The work $W$, the force $F$ and the displacement $d$ are related by the formula:

$$W = F \cdot d$$

Answer (score 2):

It is possible for a charged particle to be moving at a constant speed through space with no force acting on it (Newton's second law, $F=ma$).  If it is moving at this constant speed in a region with no electric field, then no force is acting on it, and no work can be done.

You are right though, if we are accelerating it through space by some other means, we would be doing work on the particle.

Comment: but our work done will not be stored as potential energy since there is no electric field against which we did work....right?